# Proving a function is entire

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)$ be an entire function. Prove that:
$$ g(z) = \left\{\begin{align}\frac {f(z)-f(0)}{z},\;z\ne0\\ f^\prime(0),\;z =0\end{align}\right. $$ is also entire.

I know that for $ g(z) $ to be entire, it must satisfy the C.R equations and the partial derivatives must be continuous, but how do I get the C.R equations if I do not know what $ f(z) $ looks like?

Comment: Do you know the concept of removable singularity?

Comment: Hint: $f$ is entire iff $f$ is complex analytic!

Comment: A removable singularity is a zero of the function in the denominator, but it is also a zero for the function in the numerator. Does that sound accurate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f$ is entire therefore complex analytic hence $f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {f^{(n)}(0)}{n!} z^n$. An easy calculation shows that that $g(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac {f^{(n)}(0)}{n!} z^{n-1}$ therefore $g$ is complex analytic and hence $g$ is entire.

Comment: You mean $n!$ in the denominator in the sum, right? You used Taylor expansion for the function?

Comment: Dear @Josh yes you're absolutely right!

Comment: One last question. It is necessary and sufficient for a function to be entire to be written as Taylor series. Is that correct? And in this case you did the expansion about $ z = 0 $ because that is where the function g(z) can be problematic? Or because we know it's value is equal to $f\prime(z)$ at z = 0. Sorry for all the questions. I'm trying to make sense of the problem and understand what's going on, not just get a solution. Thank you for all the help.

Comment: I also noticed that you had $f^n(0) $ in the numerator. It should be $f^{(n)} (0) $.

Comment: Dear @Josh Although its just a notation,even i have edited my answer because you prefer $(n)$ more than $n$ :).As i mentioned earlier that $f$ is complex analytic(can we expressed as power series expansion) iff $f$ is entire then one proves that Power series expansion is nothing but the Taylor expansion of the function.For all this stuff I strongly suggest you to read the classical Complex Analysis Text of Stein and Sakarchi http://www.amazon.com/Complex-Analysis-Princeton-Lectures-No/dp/0691113858.   Let me know if you have got some other doubts :)

Comment: Thank you very much. I will do that.

Comment: Dear @Josh you're welcome :)